# Clicking the button isn't calling the function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Just got around to try and create my own chrome extension, went through some tutorials online (new to HTML and JS), and decided to start off with a basic webpage opener.

The manifest loads fine, but at the moment clicking the "Open Windows" button in the popup doesn't do anything?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Switch Popup</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Open/Close</h1>
<input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the separate script file

```
function open_win()
{
    var links = ['https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.google.com'];

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: links[i]});
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `window.open(links[i], "_blank")` but note that they are considered as popups.

Comment: Open browser console and check if errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `onclick` attribute because of [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). Instead, you need to use the `addEventLinstener()` to register your event handler:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<h1>Open/Close</h1>
<input id="btnOpenWindows" type="button" value="Open Windows">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function open_win()
{
    var links = ['https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.google.com'];

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: links[i]});
    }
}

var button = document.querySelector("#btnOpenWindows");
button.addEventListener("click", open_win);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work still. I checked console and there are no errors. I even replaced the inside of the function with a simple window.open(...) call. It's just not going into the function to use it!